# Slow loading CloudKit table controller data - increasing speed?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, background-process, cloudkit, nsoperationqueue

I have 2 table controllers and a final detail controller - all the data is supplied by CloudKit.  My first table controller is quite slow loading (3-4 seconds) only to produce about 8 table cells - each cell only containing an image and label as seen below.  The second table controller is about 2-3 seconds of loading time.

```
  override   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dining") as! DiningTableCell
        let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.RestaurantName?.text = restaurant.valueForKey("Name") as? String
        let img = restaurant.objectForKey("Picture") as! CKAsset
        cell.RestaurantPhoto.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.fileURL.path!)
        return cell
    }
```

Anyways, I figure I have two opportunities to create a faster response time.  The first being, implementing dispatch(a-sync) or NSOperationQueue (unsure which to use if I'm allowing the user to select a table cell)... but something along the lines of

```
 override   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dining") as! DiningTableCell
        let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.RestaurantName?.text = restaurant.valueForKey("Name") as? String
        //NSOperationQueue Function {
        let img = restaurant.objectForKey("Picture") as! CKAsset

        cell.RestaurantPhoto.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.fileURL.path!)
        // }
        return cell
    }
```

or converting the first table controller into on device app data and then have the second table controller and detail controller load in the background.

Would implementing a background process with all CloudKit data or loading in the background of the first table controller (of on device data) be more effective?

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't recommend interacting with any of the CloudKit objects directly in your tableViewCells.  A little abstraction will go a long way.  One thing I would do is comment out the image loading and see if everything else is up to par with your speed expectation.  If so you may want to lazy load the images.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a bother, but would you mind explaining your abstraction concept and lazy loading images?  Also (& disappointly), with the image commented out, the time needed to load the cells still takes 3-4 seconds.

Comment: Sure.  Typically when working with a tableView you store the data you want in some type of collection, like an array.  Fetch the data in a background thread and then reloading the tableView (or selected rows) as needed.  I saw a good tutorial on this a while back.  I'll try to find it and post a link.

Comment: Awesome! I'd love to check it out!

Comment: It was actually a CloudKit tutorial at RayWenderlich.com.  Incredible sight for tutorials.  There are many free ones, and even more with subscription.  [This one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/83116/beginning-cloudkit-tutorial) talks about image assets, but the 2nd part (which really covers most of what you want) might be part of the paid site?  Strongly recommend all of it!

Comment: I'll take a look!  Appreciate it, DJohnson!